# PHP verify that user has access to content

Tags: php, security, acl

I am building an `ACL` plugin to my framework / application.

The previous `ACL` applications i have worked with has a `controller` / `action` verification  meaning that it checks if the user has access to both the controller and the view.

Now in many applications a `user` can have access to both the `controller` and the `view` but still not have acess to the content.

Forexample:

user1 has access to the `controller`: games and the `view`: play but not have access to the `id`: 1

My first idea was to check the `$_GET` variable but this is not sufficient since it is impossible to know what the variable that the content is looking for.

So my question is how would you verify that the user has access to the content of the view?

Comment: Why do you have access control imposed on the view? This type of checks should be entirely take place in the controller. (As long as we talk regular MVC here.)

Comment: Can't be answered except in the most general terms. Obviously you have to write code that knows who should be able to "view" the "widget" with id "1" and you need to somehow call it as part of handling the request.

Comment: the check happens in the controller however if you have a permission table a user could have access to both the controller and the view but not the $_GET['id'] = 1

Comment: @Jon i am thinking that this is a problem that fairly often occour when writing ACL?

Comment: @MarcRasmussen: It totally depends on your requirements. Fairly often is IMO pretty close to the truth but what difference does it make?

Comment: @Jon If you have serveral users making content you want to make sure that other users cannot reach that content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you do know the id of the content in your Controller and you do know the user trying to access it. Just add contentId to your ACL check routine? You just have to add more ACL data, current implementation with just controller and method isn't enough in these cases.

e.g. $acl->userIsAllowedTo('view', 1, 'gamescontroller') or so.

Comment: This could work however it is not always that the $_GET variable is named id and there might be serveral $_GET variables. How would i differ?

Comment: Oh, I see - name of the variable might change. Do you know the possible names of Id variables coming in get? If not, then there isn't much other things to do than to standardize the input values.

Comment: (In other hand, I don't understand how and why the name of the variable you bring content ID's in would change that much)

Comment: it is very depending on the view and i want to make it as generic as possible

Comment: But your Controllers must know the Id anyway in order to show the correct content. Therefore you can store the id in whatever format in your ACL persistence. 

So, give your ACL as parameter to Controller and let controller ask from ACL. Not the ideal solution as then your controller must know what to do when authorisation fails. It would be more ideal to check ACL before calling Controller.